# How do I set the order of construction of beans in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am working on a Spring based application and I have a requirement, that I want a particular bean to be constructed before any other bean.

How can I specify the order in which beans are constructed in Spring?

To clarify, I want the constructor + post construct of a particular bean to be executed before the constructor of other beans.

Comment: Why? What makes this bean special?

Comment: This bean sets some system wide configurations that will be required by other beans in order to start.

Comment: Spring will make take care of dependencies being initialized.

Comment: The first bean is setting configurations on a Zookeeper server, while the rest will be reading this configuration. As far as I know (and what running the code is showing) Spring will not be aware of this and will not be able to take care of these dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [depends-on](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html).  Any beans specified are guaranteed to be created by the container before bean with annotation.

```
@Bean
@DependsOn({"firstBean", "secondBean"})
class MyBean {}
```

You can also specify if on xml:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="MyBean" depends-on="firstBean, secondBean">
</bean>
```

Comment: I have thought about this, but, in our scenario, it would not be a reasonable solution to have all the beans depend on a single bean, simply due to maintaining code. Unfortunately the application is quite large and constantly growing.

Comment: @stikku - How did you solve your problem about you wanted a specific bean to be the first to be constructed?

Comment: @Noam could not find any solution other than using dependencies, had to change a bit the logic in my application. I'm now using @Autowired(required = false)
    private List<MyObject> myobject; just to force the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

It might help (if you control the code of the beans themselves) to leverage the `@PostConstruct` annotation on a method.

- Do your bean agnostic initialization in a constructor
- Let Spring wire everything together
- Then have all of your bean dependent setup in a method marked with `@PostContstruct`

This way, you should not (at least I've not seen it) require any order of bean initialization.  Everything will get created, injected, then started in a Spring friendly lifecycle.

FYI, there is also a `@PreDestroy` for cleanup if you need it.

Simple example here: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-postconstruct-and-predestroy-example/

Comment: This does not work. (just tested this to make sure) Given two beans (A and B) spring will construct A, run the @PostConstruct of A, and only after that will it construct B. The reason behind post construct is to execute code after the bean itself has been constructed and is not related to any other beans.

Comment: @stikku  this is not true.  From the docs: [PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) `PostConstruct annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed after dependency injection is done to perform any initialization`

Comment: your statement is correct, but PostConstruct in no way effects order of beans, it is simply exected immediately after the construction of this bean, but before the construction of the bean. Therefore irrelevant to this question.

Comment: If order is required, @Randall gave you the way to do it.  I was providing an alternative since you said you cannot use his approach.  This would allow order to not matter, and should be considered relevant.